# HTML CSS- javascript .click() event

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fellow friends, im have a bit of a hard time figuring this out, and decided to ask you guys...

I have the following HTML structure(more or less):

```
<li>
  <a>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </a>
</li>
```

divs are set to inline-blocks, anchor is set to block
The list element has a css hover class and an active/clicked mode class. 
The hover styling is working on li.hover: hover but the clicked class is not working for me since the click event is triggering the childrens handlers(the divs) and not the list..

So my question is, how can I set the parent to be the clickable element rather then the children.. And if you could shed some light on why it is different with the hover event(why hover event handler of the parent is triggered,and not the children's, like with the click ), that would be super awsome as I want to fully understand how css and event work.

Edit-

I have a jquery event handler ..

```
$(".mylist").click(function(e){
$(this).addClass('selected');

});
```

The problem is that this doesnt fire as when I click it seems that the divs are 'overlapping' the parent.. Also do not wish to use z-index.. (but I  do not know if its the way to go) 
thanks 
regards

Comment: why dont you put anchor as parent of li element?

Comment: What was the code that you used that was not working?

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript or javascript library like jQuery? I think what youa trying to do can easly be accomplished through javascript ...

Comment: I am confused: are you having trouble with css or javascript? Or is it both? What are you expecting to happen when the element is clicked?

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes im quite familiar with JS and jquery.. M.Svrcek does it affect what im trying to accomplish? Nick I thinks its an easy fix of simply setting something with css in order to make the LI element be the one which is clickable rather than the children..

Comment: Also note the javascript is not launching rockets or anything so I m sure the js code is correct. simply adding a class called selected to the list element

Comment: Just put the handler on the `<li>` element?  Why do you have event handlers on the children if you don't want them to be clickable?

Comment: Changing CSS will not change how your click event is working.

Comment: @Pointy I do not have event handlers on the children.. Only one event handler on the li element. I never mentioned anything about having a handler for the children.. if I did, then sorry, I do not have event handlers for the div elements.

Comment: @Nick I know it wont change how a click event works.. But it will certainly affect if its triggered or not.. for instance a hidden element cannot really fire an event can it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click your `div` a click event bubbles up through `a` to `li`. So if you add your listener to the `li` instead of the divs then everything should work.

Of course if your click handler for the `div` calls `event.stopPropagation` then your handler for `li` would not work. Same with click handler on `a` element.

Comment: Yes I have read about bubbling up etc. and I am adding the listener to the li element not the divs, that is why I am confused

Comment: Actually, this solved my problem as i had and event.preventdefault in the li.click event handler rather than on the a.click event. Many thanks for this!